# How to make output continue the program instead of just the first part then ending. Is this from not callinng all functions within main?

Tags: c++

It will allow user input for current time then won't continue to display menu then add time.

Do need to have all functions ran inside the main and how do I do that. Although I'm new to C++ and very confused. When ran individually it works but everything after the main won't execute to output as if its not called in main. How can I resolve this?

This is the code I have

```
 '''c++
    #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <iomanip>
        
        using namespace std;
        
        int main() {
        
            cout << "**************************\n"
                 << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
                 << "*\t1-Add One Hour\t\t*\n"
                 << "*\t2-Add One Minute\t*\n"
                 << "*\t3-Add One Second\t*\n"
                 << "*\t4-Exit Program\t\t*\n"
                 << "**************************\n";
        }
        
        void displayTime(int &hour12, int &min12, int &sec12, string &ampm, int &hour24,
                          int &min24, int &sec24) {
        
            cout << "**************************\n"
                 << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
                 << "*\t12-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
                 << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":"
                 << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << "\t*\n"
                 << "*\t24-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
                 << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour24 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min24 << ":"
                 << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec24 << "\t*\n"
                 << "**************************\n";
        }
        
        void addOneHour (int &hour ) {
        
            hour++;
        }
        
        void addOneMin(int &min) {
        
            min++;
        }
        
        void addOneSec (int &sec) {
        
            sec++;
        }
        
        int displayMenu() {
        
            int hour12, min12, sec12;
            string ampm;
        
            cout << "Please enter the initial time in 12-hour format (HH:MM:SS AM/PM): ";
            cin >> hour12 >> min12 >> sec12 >> ampm;
        
            cout << "The initial time is: " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << endl;
        
            int hour24 = hour12;
            if (ampm == "PM") {
                hour24 += 12;
            }
        
            int min24 = min12;
            int sec24 = sec12;
        
            displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
            displayMenu();
        
            int choice;
            cin >> choice;
        
            while (choice != 4) {
        
                switch (choice) {
        
                    case 1:
                        addOneHour(hour12);
                        hour24++;
                        break;
        
                    case 2:
                        addOneMin(min12);
                        min24++;
                        break;
        
                    case 3:
                        addOneSec(sec12);
                        sec24++;
                        break;
        
                    default:
                        cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again." << endl;
                        break;
                }
        
                if (hour12 > 12) {
                    hour12 -= 12;
                    ampm = "PM";
                } else if (hour12 == 12) {
                    ampm = "PM";
                } else {
                    ampm = "AM";
                }
        
                if (hour24 >= 24) {
                    hour24 -= 24;
                }
        
                if (min24 >= 60) {
                    min24 -= 60;
                    hour24++;
                }
        
                if (sec24 >= 60) {
                    sec24 -= 60;
                    min24++;
                }
        
                displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
                displayMenu();
        
                cin >> choice;
            }
        
            cout << "Exiting program. Goodbye!" << endl;
        
            return 0;
        }
    '''
```

This is the flowchart I'm trying to use to complete this.

START Program

Get User Input for the Initial Time

LOOP

Display Menu (Process)

IF Add Hour? (Decision)

Add Hour (Process)
Display Time (Process)

IF Add Minute? (Decision)

Add Minute (Process)
Display Time (Process)

IF Add Second? (Decision)

Add Second (Process)
Display Time (Process)

IF EXIT? (Decision)

Exit (Process)
END LOOP

---

I also have an alternative C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int hour12, min12, sec12;
    string ampm;

    cout << "Please enter the initial time in 12-hour format (HH:MM:SS AM/PM): ";
    cin >> hour12 >> min12 >> sec12 >> ampm;

    cout << "The initial time is: " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << endl;

}
void displayMenu( ) {

    cout << "**************************\n"
         << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t1-Add One Hour\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t2-Add One Minute\t*\n"
         << "*\t3-Add One Second\t*\n"
         << "*\t4-Exit Program\t\t*\n"
         << "**************************\n";
}

void displayTime(int &hour12, int &min12, int &sec12, string &ampm, int &hour24,
                  int &min24, int &sec24) {

    cout << "**************************\n"
         << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t12-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":"
         << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << "\t*\n"
         << "*\t24-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour24 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min24 << ":"
         << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec24 << "\t*\n"
         << "**************************\n";
}

void addOneHour (int &hour ) {

    hour++;
}

void addOneMin(int &min) {

    min++;
}

void addOneSec (int &sec) {

    sec++;
}

void displayTime() {
    int hour12 = 12, min12 = 0, sec12 = 0, hour24 = 0, min24 = 0, sec24 = 0;
    string ampm = "AM";



    displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
    displayMenu();

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice != 4) {

        switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                addOneHour(hour12);
                hour24++;
                break;

            case 2:
                addOneMin(min12);
                min24++;
                break;

            case 3:
                addOneSec(sec12);
                sec24++;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
        }

        if (hour12 == 12 && min12 == 0 && sec12 == 0 && ampm == "AM") {

            ampm = "PM";
        }
        else if (hour12 == 12 && min12 == 0 && sec12 == 0 && ampm == "PM") {

            ampm = "AM";
        }
        else if (hour12 > 12) {

            hour12 -= 12;
            ampm = "PM";
        }

        if (min24 == 60) {

            min24 = 0;
            hour24++;
        }

        if (sec24 == 60) {

            sec24 = 0;
            min24++;
        }

        if (hour24 == 24) {

            hour24 = 0;
        }

        displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
        displayMenu();

        cin >> choice;
    }

    cout << "Goodbye!\n";

}
```

Comment: *"Please help me get this program working..."* Are you getting any error? If yes, kindly add the complete error in your question. What does "working" mean?

Comment: This is something very basic that any beginners course, tutorial or class should have taught you.

Comment: And looking in your functions, you already know how to call a function. So what is the problem with calling the functions from your `main` function? Is it that you have forgotten that all symbols (variables, classes, ***functions***) needs to be *declared* before you use them?

Comment: I think this is a dupe: [Calling a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925990/calling-functions-within-another-function) and [Calling a function inside `main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916162/calling-a-function-in-main). Also note that the program [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/4ffbGv7Td).

Comment: From the names of your functions and their bodies, it looks like you've swapped the names `main` and `displayMenu`. I.e. you should have `void displayMenu` with the `cout << stuff` and `int main` with the long sequence ending in `cout << "Goodbye"`

Comment: E.g. [like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27c4e60935a2dd47)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the content of the main function is what is executed when you run the program. All other functions that you have defined need to be called from within the main function in order to be executed.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP's asking. They're asking *"how do I to call all my functions in main"* and this answer doesn't answer that.